# Catalog select list (ajax)

Tags: views

This question of how to create such a directory http://gospodar.org/ with ready-made solutions, only to drop down the list was to Ajax?
Catalog at the link above is made by custom module and not very comfortable.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: "samopisnogo module" is a custom module or contributed module?

Comment: Sorry for my English. 'custom module'